# Identificar el formulario del que se proviene

Tags: php, html, formularios

En mi página web tengo dos secciones: `compras` y `ventas`

Cada una con un `layout` diferente. En cada una el usuario puede consultar sus datos personales y modificarlos, el caso es que al estar mostrando la misma información me interesaría usar el mismo script `php` en ambas situaciones. Para mostrar los datos no hay ningún problema, pero a la hora de hacer los `UPDATE` a la base de datos el script re-dirige al usuario a otra página, en este caso a la página principal de compras.

Pero aunque el usuario modificase los datos desde la sección de ventas también lo re-dirigiría a la sección de compras ya que no sé de que manera diferenciar dónde se encuentra el usuario.

El código que tengo:

```
//hago la conexión con la bdd, etc.
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

//consulta sql
$registro="UPDATE usu_datos SET Usu_Nom = '$nom' WHERE Usu_Usu = '$usr'; "                
. "UPDATE usu_datos SET Usu_Apel = '$apl' WHERE Usu_Usu = '$usr'; ";

$resultados= mysqli_multi_query($conexion, $registro);

//verificación de los resultados
if($resultados==false){
}else{
    //aquí mi PROBLEMA, ahora re-dirige al siguiente enlace
    header('Location:../login/compras.php');

    //pero dependiendo de la sección tendría que re-dirigir a otro lugar
    header('Location:../login/ventas.php');

}
```

El formulario actual usado en la sección de compras y en la de ventas es el mismo:

```
<form  name="form1" method="post" action="../validadores_datos_usuario/validar_datos_usuario.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul style="width: 60%; float: left;">
        <li>
            <label class="usrDataLbl " for="nombre"> Nombre</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input  class="usrData shadow noBorder" id="usrNombre"  type="text" name="nombre" value=<?php echo "'" . $nombre . "'" ?> >
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="usrDataLbl" for="apellidos"> Apellidos</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input  class="usrData shadow noBorder" id="usrApellidos" type="text" name="apellidos" value=<?php echo "'" . $apellidos . "'" ?> >
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="usrDataLbl " for="usuario"> Usuario</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="usrData shadow noBorder" id="usrUsuario" type="zz" name="usuario" value=<?php echo "'" . $usuario . "'" ?> disabled> </li>
        <li>
            <label class="usrDataLbl" for="pregunta_seguridad"> Pregunta de seguridad</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input  class="usrData shadow noBorder" id="usrUsuario " type="text" name="pregunta_seguridad" readonly value=<?php echo "'" . $pregunta . "'" ?>>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="usrDataLbl" for="pregunta_seguridad"> Respuesta de seguridad</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="usrData shadow noBorder" id="usrUsuario " type="text" name="respuesta_seguridad" readonly value=<?php echo "'" . $respuesta . "'" ?>>
        </li>
        <li class="margin-top-10"></li>
        <li>
            <input class="botonTipo1 margin-top-10 margin-right-10" type="submit" name="guardar_dat_usr" id="btn-validarDatosPersonales" value="Guardar" >
            <input type="reset" class="botonTipo2 margin-top-10" onclick="cancelarInfoUsr()" value="Cancelar">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="float: right; width:250px; height: 250px; border: 7px solid rgb(230,230,230); overflow: hidden ">
 <img style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; " src=<?php echo $foto ?> >
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="imagen" id="prodImg_1" class="shadow inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} archivos seleccionados" multiple />
    <label style="float: right; margin-top: 10px; width: 250px" for="prodImg_1">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" style="font-size:24px"></i>
        <span class="iborrainputfile">Seleccionar archivo</span>
    </label>
    <img id="target"/>
</form>
```

¿Hay algún método de identificar desde qué formulario se introducen los datos para así escoger la página de destino?

Comment: Hola @gmarsi tienes un error y es el siguiente, no puedes decir, 
else{
    //aquí mi PROBLEMA, ahora re-dirige al siguiente enlace
    header('Location:../login/compras.php');

    //pero dependiendo de la sección tendría que re-dirigir a otro lugar
    header('Location:../login/ventas.php');

}
porque PHP quedaria loco...se podria decir "que el tomaria la primera redireccion que encuentre en el camino por decirlo asi o en el else" mas bien redirigelo una ves al login y en el login haces la validacion porque sino nunca te va a funcionar.

Comment: y siempre se te va a redirigir a compras, de igualmanera si tu pones ventas de primero siempre se te va a redirigir a ventas porque toma la primera redireccion y mas si estas usando un header:location.

Comment: si ya encontraste la respuesta, porfavor añadela como respuesta a tu propia pregunta y seleccionala como la solucion, o porfavor selecciona la respuesta que te ayudo a solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de hecho hay varias maneras de hacerlo

**1:** Usando el action de tu formualrio
ej:

```
<form  name="form1" method="post" action="../validadores_datos_usuario/validar_datos_usuario.php?form=formIdentifier" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

de esta manera en tu php capturas la variable form asi:

```
$_GET['form'];
```

y operas lo que necesitas.

**2:** Si lo haces por JS el envio, solo creas un parametro con el nombre de tu formulario algo asi:

```
data: { var1: 'myData1', form: 'myForm' }
```

y lo procesar como una variable normal en tu php

**3:** Crear un campo escondido en tu form que lleve el nombre de tu formulario, lo capturas en tu PHP y procesas para lo q tengas que hacer.
ej:

```
<input type="hidden" id="formName" value="myForm">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Frank, he usado a primera opción!! Saludos :D